# Query if a Distribution List is being used in a sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a way to query the sharepoint if a particular `Distribution List` is being used in SharePoint 2016 on-prem?  We have a lot of DL's which now are going to delete and/or rename.

The worry of renaming a DL is: will the WF detect the new DL name and continu as normal?
The crucial part is, to identify which DLs are being used to know which can be deleted.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to get what you are looking for. SharePoint workflow details are in XAML (xml) format and can be retrieved from several SharePoint APIs.

You should be able to retrieve the XAML with a PowerShell PNP cmdlet. (Get-PnPWorkflowDefinition) Note that Get-PnPWorkflowDefinition is deprecated in the current version of the PNP library. This were deprecated due to workflows being deprecated in SharePoint Online. If you can't find it, or an older version of the library, there is a direct web service call alternate (The PNP cmdlets internally call web services.)

Otherwise for SharePoint On-Prem, do a web search for New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager. You would need to run this PowerShell code on the SharePoint server.

If you are a .NET developer, you could run code against this same object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager, again running the code on the SharePoint server.

You would need to retrieve each workflow, extract the XAML and check for the distribution list name. If the list names are reasonably unique you could just do a string search of the XAML, otherwise you would use PowerShell or .NET to convert it to an XML Document and then parse it.

Comment: Smith - NCT - NVP . Sadly I am not a developer :( and I would struggle to do any codings. I was hoping for a settings via the Center Adminstration of SP2016 OnPrem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't any option in Central Administration that will find that for you.